# Visual Studio close all documents after restart

Tags: visual-studio

For no reason after close my solution and re-open, all the documents (tabs) that I had open, are closed.

I already look in "options" for some configuration, but I didn't find nothing

Comment: Why do you mean by `closed`? Can you reopen them?

Comment: I mean the tabs. I can reopen.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try reset your layout: `Window -> Reset window layout`.

Comment: Ha, awesome. Worked for me too. VS 2017crashed for me while debugging a project. From that point, every time I reopened the project it would be in the state it was in at the crash, showing all the pages and tabs I had open at that time (instead of the page and tabs of my most recent session). 'Reset Window Layout' must do a lot more under the covers than simply resetting the layout. Worked anyway, so that's great. Cheers!